# Delete from InnoDB table without having a binary log

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-administration

I have an InnoDB table used to pre-process some data before rendering a web page. It is a very bulky table. And; I do not need to keep some old records it it.

To keep the database size slim, I need to delete the data. But partially only.
TRUNCATE does not work, but DELETE.

Will the database create a bigger log files with this?
Is there a way to delete the data without producing a binary log?

Comment: there is a way, but normally you shouldn't do that to avoid inconsistencies between master and slaves. Binary logs are rotated. If not check variable expire_log_days

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql option named [`--binlog-ignore-db`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-ignore-db) so that particular db is not logged in binary log. so create your bulky table in binlog ignored db.

Also, you can use [`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) so that temp table will be deleted after session closed.

Comment: Looks the first option will be better; because I will have to retain the data permanently; and delete only on demand.

Comment: @BimalPoudel Right. I just suggested `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` for your covenient. I didn't knew that it would be needed permanently.